# Reference request: unique minimal model in birational class for a complex surface of general type (which may not be smooth)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

Frankly I know nothing about this type of algebraic geometry (or any kind of graduate level AG), but I need at one point in an article to say "there exists a unique minimal model, since the surface is of general type", and I can't seem to find a reference for this statement.

I also have a hunch that for some surfaces, being minimal is equivalent to having no (-1)     curves? It would be nice to able to state it in this fashion, since I understand what that means...!

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: In general, if a smooth compact complex surface has Kodaira dimenison $\ge 0$, then the minimal model is unique, see Barth-Hulek-Peteres-Van de ven's _Compact Complex Surfaces_, chapter III, prop. 4.6. Besides, being minimal is the same as no $(-1)$ curve is right.

Answer (score 0):

Such a reference can be located by searching for the correct words on your favorite search engine and a little persistence. For instance, starting with "minimal models for surfaces," one arrives at the [Wikipedia page for the minimal model program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_program), reads down to the section on minimal models of surfaces, which links to the page on the [Enriques-Kodaira classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriques%E2%80%93Kodaira_classification), and in the references on this page there are a great many sources. One which is freely available on the internet is [Chapters on Algebraic Surfaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf), by Miles Reid, which contains the result you ask for in section C.3 on page 57.